# tzupdater failures with 2020b & 2020c

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, iana

Today [iana released timezone db update for 2020b](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2020-October/000059.html) version. Java's [tzupdater tool](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-tzupdater-downloads.html) (2.3.1) from oracle fails to patch OpenJDK8u265.

```
$ java -jar tzupdater.jar -v -u -f -l file:tzdata-latest.tar.gz
Using file:tzdata-latest.tar.gz as source for tzdata bundle.
java.home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
java.vendor: AdoptOpenJDK
java.version: 1.8.0_265
tzupdater version 2.3.1-b02
JRE tzdata version: tzdata2020a
Downloaded file to /var/folders/k4/d4wwf5sd71b0hnp7lvrv1wk40000gn/T/tz.tmp_6/tzdata.tar.gz
tzupdater tool would update with tzdata version: tzdata2020b
Source directory does not contain source file: pacificnew
$ echo $?
1
```

---

with 2020c update

```
tzupdater tool would update with tzdata version: tzdata2020c
Source directory does not contain source file: africa
```

**Update**

This was recognized as a bug by Oracle https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8255747 and it is fixed as part of tzupdater release 2.3.2 - still waiting for the release to be published.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue, we used to use the https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tzdata-latest.tar.gz URL and they apparently deployed a new version recently.

Quick fix: Try to use the previous version: https://data.iana.org/time-zones/releases/tzdata2020a.tar.gz :)

Comment: Thanks! What is the sha256 hash for the package that worked for you ? `$sha256sum tzdata-latest.tar.gz.4
9b053f951d245ce89d850b96ee4711d82d833559b1fc96ba19f90bc4d745e809  tzdata-latest.tar.gz.4` This still fails

Answer (score 1):

A workaround if you need the updates is to take the file pacificnew from the tarfile tzdata2020a.tar.gz and add it to the tar file you want to use.

**Update**
Timezone Updater 2.3.2 was released today

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed with [tzupdater at version 2.3.2](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/tzupdater-readme.html) as part of [JDK-8254226](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8254226)